# Best strategy to persist ISO8601

Tags: java, rest, datetime, jodatime

I have been reading different articles on the said question yet i am unable to figure out what should be the best strategy to store the date in db.

I will be receiving the ISO8601 date via `path-param` in a rest call. What I have decided

1. Use `Joda-Time` to parse the date.
2. Extract `UTC-0` time out of the date and the hours offset
3. Store `UTC-0` in `DateTime` datatype in `mysql` db and store `offset` in `varchar(5)`.
4. When I have to search something based on the date (an exposed rest api). I will use the search criteria (input date) extract the `UTC-0` time and `hours offset` and compare the two columns in the db i.e. `where table.dateInUTC0 = :inputDateInUTC0  AND table.hoursOffset = :inputHoursOffset`

I am not sure about step 4. Am i doing i right ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure about step 4. Am i doing i right ?

Really, it depends on what you are *trying* to do.

- If you want the search to only match if the searcher is using the same timezone as the original data, then you are doing it right.
- If you don't want that, you are doing it wrong.

Ask yourself this: If you enter the same date / time in your local time zone and UTC (or some other time zone), do they *mean* the same thing for clients of your server?  Should they?